# Invalid connection string attributes when connecting via odbcConnection

Tags: c#, odbc

I'm trying to build a C# WPF application that can connect to multiple types of databases via DSN and I've hit a snag. Normally the connection info (username/password) is entirely stated in the ODBC connection but when trying to connect to an SQL server (that I set up for test purposes) I've run into some problems.

If I try

```
string connString = $"DSN={dsn};";
OdbcConnection cnn = new OdbcConnection(connString);
cnn.Open()
```

I get an error

> "Login failed for user ''."

If I change the connection string to specifically state the username and password like

```
string connString = $"DSN={dsn}; UID = {username}; PW = {password};";
```

I get the same error plus

> Invalid connection string attribute

I've tried different versions of this after searching for different connection string examples but I'm stumped. It appears like the server is returning an error that I passed it the username '' rather than the actual login name (CCLogin), and also that the connection string is in the wrong format but I can't find any problems with the format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying the username with UID is correct, but the password attribute is PWD - you're missing the trailing D.  That's what it complains of.  The login failure is extemporaneous - it has no password, but that's a secondary problem.  You'll likely also find that it's unhappy with DSN - ODBC favors Server={Server};Database={database}.  Typically you'll also specify a driver so a full ODBC connection string would look like one of (assuming  you're using Sql Server):

`Driver={Sql Server};Server=servername;Database=db_name;Uid=username;Pwd=password;`

or, if it's a trusted connection (using the same credentials as your windows login)

`Driver={Sql Server};Server=servername;Database=db_name;Trusted Connection=Yes;`

Start with whichever of those is appropriate and, assuming it works, if you want to then experiment to find what the base MINIMUM is, you can start by eliminating one key-value pair at a time until it breaks.  As a bit of advice, though, I'd suggest using the long-form.

If your server is using other than SQL Server, look for the driver name by searching for "ODBC Data Source Administration".  That will give you the appropriate application and the driver you're using should be listed there.

ODBC has the benefit of being old and very stable, but it tends to be fussy about how you set it up.  The good news is that once set up properly, it'll behave for decades without a blip.

Comment: So by this logic - assuming I want the database connection to come from an ODBC datasource - I need to actually query all of these settings from the registry based on which DSN the user selects?

Comment: If you don't know off the top of your head what *drivers* are available to the client using your software, then you've missed a step, because you should be *supplying* a driver if there is any doubt about whether or not their system will have the correct one for your datasource.  Once that is installed, that's the one you use.  Unless, of course, it's an SQL driver and Windows OS (the driver has been coming with the OS for years), so under those constraints it's safe to consider it's availability /fiat accompli/.

Comment: In this case, the application is designed to use odbc drivers supplied by the user to connect to sql databases supplied by the user. I will know the structure of the database in order to complete a few specific queries but the idea is to allow flexibility as this is a support tool.

Comment: Hmm.  That could take a little experimentation on your part.  Again, if the client-supplied DB is SQL Server or one of the other pre-installed drivers, you should be free and clear - even in the worst case you can simply run through the list of available drivers on that system and try them all.  If the DB is on their system, then they've likely got the correct driver installed.  If they have to find one, then from your description it's probably within their capabilities to do so but it's hard to depend on that.